# Render another project in Yii`s view

Tags: php, yii

I have a Yii based application and another HTML5 and CSS based small application.

**Yii based app:** localhost/yii
**HTML 5 project:** localhost/yii/htmlproject

I created a controller that have an action

```
public function actionView(){

}
```

I need a way to render the whole "HTML 5 Project" to this view. Would it be possible?

**Note:** The above mentioned links work perfectly.

Comment: yii1 or yii2 ? please ..

Comment: Can't you just use a redirection header inside that method?

Comment: scaisEdge Yii 2
@AlexTartan Well the problem is that in the controller i have two actions, one that have the login page and the other where i want to render the whole project.  I want to make sure that if i login and session has been created then user should be allowed to access the project, now do you think redirection header would work for that? And by redirection header you mean using $this->redirect?

Comment: @OsamaYawar, I'm assuming you're just starting on this project. Instead of trying to make `Yii` work for some html files, make those html files work for `Yii`. See this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-getting-started--cms-22440 Using the expected file hierarchy you avoid situations like this.

Comment: @AlexTartan Its a need actually and that is the reason i cannot make them work for Yii.